# google.golang.org/grpc not getting installed propely, PeerCertificates[0].URIs undefined (type *x509.Certificate has no field or method URIs)

Tags: linux, go, grpc-go

my go version is "go version go1.9.4 linux/amd64"
On running "go get -u google.golang.org/grpc", a "go" drectory gets created in my HOME and i get the following messages

## google.golang.org/grpc/internal/credentials

go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/internal/credentials/spiffe.go:39:70: state.PeerCertificates[0].URIs undefined (type *x509.Certificate has no field or method URIs)
go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/internal/credentials/spiffe.go:48:24: cert.URIs undefined (type *x509.Certificate has no field or method URIs)
go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/internal/credentials/spiffe.go:52:26: cert.URIs undefined (type *x509.Certificate has no field or method URIs)
go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/internal/credentials/spiffe.go:70:14: cert.URIs undefined (type *x509.Certificate has no field or method URIs)

its giving the same error if i try to run a grpc server boiler plate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go 1.9 is too old to build that package. The `URIs` field is [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate) as having been added to the Certificate struct in Go 1.10 (released in early 2018).